# Are there any fonts close to this?

Tags: font-identification

I'm designing a cake design and am wondering if there are any fonts close to the accompanying image? Have been searching far and wide, with not much luck.

[image]

Comment: Why dont you make that into a font?

Comment: your image is here http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-64009.html . See the accompanying texts

Answer (score 4):

[FS Bezier Pixel](https://smartfonts.com/fs-bezier-pixel.font) via SmartFonts.com

[image]

Comment: Very good find,